# Highlighting lines starting with #IF... using User Defined Language in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, user-defined

I want to use syntax highlighting in Notepad++ for a script language that I'm working with. I set up keywords and stuff in "User Defined Language" and pretty much everything works as I'd like it to except for the following:

The script language uses `#IF` and `#ENDIF` (just like C), but I can't figure out how to configure Notepad++ so that entire lines starting with `#IF` or `#ENDIF` are highlighted (just like it is in C).

Using keywords, only the keywords `#IF` and `#ENDIF` are highlighted and not the entire line.
Operators & Delimiters doesn't work either since there is no closing delimiter for lines with these statements.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**It can be kludged in as a comment style.**

You can do this by defining `#IF` and `#ENDIF` as two possible beginnings of a comment line.

[image]

---

**An alternate method is to make `#IF` and `#ENDIF` delimiters.**

[image]

The delimiters `#IF` and `#ENDIF` just need to have their end markers as the end of the line. [The special keyword 'EOL' expands to a vector of three strings](http://udl20.weebly.com/comments.html): "\r\n", "\n", and "\r"